# Usage of CDN in Hybris solutions

Tags: e-commerce, cdn, sap-commerce-cloud

I am exploring the support and usage of CDN in a Hybris solution.

I am a Hybris newbie and am working through the wiki to understand the product better.

I am unable to find the answers based on my search of CDN in conjuction with Hybris.

What are the typical CDN Providers that are used in an Hybris solution? Any references would be helpful.

Appreciate any pointers.

PS: This is not a programming question. If this question is considered inappropriate let me know and I will delete this.

Answer (score 2):

Why would there be any preferred CDN providers? You can choose any provider you want but take these questions into consideration:

- How is the TTL defined? By cache headers (set by hybris) or manually set on the CDN’s side? The possible cache headers are `Cache-Control`, `Surrogate-Control` and `Edge-Control`. Akamai for example uses `Edge-Control` but I’m not aware that any other CDN uses this header.
- The choice of your CDN will also depend on where the content will be required: do you need to serve it worldwide or do you want to improve your quality of service in certains areas only by adding POPs?
- Does content sometimes need to be invalidated from the cache? If yes, check if there is an API to do so (will require work to make hybris communicate with the API).

The easiest solution would be a basic cache where the TTLs would be defined in the CDN’s configuration.
If you choose to go with cache headers, this is a quite simple solution to setup in hybris, you only have to define a request handler that will take care of them.

Answer (score 2):

Hybris is usually used for some sort of ecommerce site. I have seen great results by using ImageEngine.io for an image specific CDN for Hybris. ImageEngine optimizes images on the fly which makes your site load faster. Worth a look: http://imageengine.io